# cannot connect two bones together

Tags: rigging

[image]

i want to connect bone 1 and 2 together however i am not able parent any to the other

notice that bone 1 is not in the same group as of bone 2
, basically group "2" is a duplicate of group "1" with a rotation of 180 degrees about the z-axis

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In edit mode select the head only of bone 1, then press Shift S "Cursor to selected", then select the tail only of bone 2 and presse shift S "selection to cursor". Then select the bone 1, shift select the bone 2, and press Ctrl P "Connected". Different bone groups are not a problem because they are referred to pose mode, not edit mode.

Comment: they still do not connect : [image](https://imgur.com/qv6NswI)

Comment: There are two ipothesis: or you didn't follow the procedure exactly, or your file has some starnge issue. In this latter case you should upload your file, to inspect.

Answer (score 0):

1. To do that, go to edit-mode and Select the Tail of the bone to which you want the disconnected bone to be connected, and press Shift+S to set 3D cursor to tail.

[image: set cursor to tail of bone]

2. Now select the Head of Disconnected bone, press Shift+S to set the selection to 3D cursor. this will copy the transformations of child bone's tail to the head of parent bone.
   [image: set selection to 3D cursor]
3. At last just select the child bone press Shift and select parent bone, Then press ctrl+P to Connect Bones.

[image: connect the child bone to parent bone]